# How to access NH QueryOver aliases from other functions and classes?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I want to be able to use one particular query in several other functions, I have a class that just creates a specialized QueryOver object for a particular domain.

But that function uses alias objects to create the joins.  How can I access those aliases from another function?

For example say I have Course entities that each have a collection of students.
And I always want to only get `Active` ( a bool value) courses

```
public class QueryHelperClass
{
  public QueryOver<Course, Course> GetQuery()
  {
      Address studentAlias = null;
      QueryOver<Course, Course> query = QueryOver.Of<Course>(() => courseAlias)
       .JoinAlias(x => cus.Student, () => studentAlias)
       .Where(x => courseAlias.IsActive);
      return query;
  }
}
```

That works fine if all I need to do is GetExecutableQuery and return the results, but what do I do if I need to modify the query by accessing `studentAlias`?

Example:

```
public class SomeOtherClass
{
  public List<Course> GetActiveCourseSummary(QueryOver<Course, Course> queryOver)
  {
      var query = queryOver.Where(a=> studentAlias.Name = "Bob");
      ...
  }
}
```

From the `SomeOtherClass.GetActiveCourseSummary` I want to modify the query to only get courses where "Bob" is enrolled. But I can't access the studentAlias because it was defined in another function.

What can I do here, or am I setting this up all completely hard-core incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

In fact, we can *re-declare* the same variable in `SomeOtherClass`.

```
public List<Course> GetActiveCourseSummary(QueryOver<Course, Course> queryOver)
{
    Address studentAlias = null;
    var query = queryOver.Where(() => studentAlias.Name == "Bob");
    ...
}
```

The point is, that the name `studentAlias` (of the local variable *Address*) is the same as in the method `GetQuery()`.

This will work, because what we pass in the `.Where()` method is the `Expression`. It is parsed and its string part `"studentAlias"` is used the same way as before, in *GetQuery()*.

BUT

I would say, that this is not the way I would use. It is not clear what is passed into `SomeOtherClass`, how the query was built. There already could be an alias, but also it could be just a simple `QueryOver<Course, Course> queryOver`.

*My approach is to do it different way. Collect all restrictions all the way down. Once there is e.g. set of restrictions `IList<ICriterion>`, call the DAO method, create query and append these restrictions at one place. But it is different story*

If we would like to get some more checks into *SomeOtherClass*: we can use the Criteria API. Down side is that we have to usestring representation of properties "Student" and "Code" (not so clean as *QueryOver API*)

```
public List<Course> GetActiveCourseSummary(QueryOver<Course, Course> queryOver)
{
    var criteria = query.UnderlyingCriteria;
    var rootAlias = criteria.Alias;              // will return "courseAlias"
    var path = rootAlias + ".Student";           // the path
    var student = criteria.GetCriteriaByPath(path)
            ?? criteria.CreateCriteria(path, path);
    var studentAlias = student.Alias;            // finally we do have existing alias
    queryOver.And(Restrictions.Eq(studentAlias + ".Name ", "Bob"));
    ...
```